# Why the same powers of $p$ divide $p^{\alpha}m-i$ and $p^{\alpha}-i$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

This question is from Herstein's Topics in algebra,2nd edition, page 92:

> If $n=p^{\alpha}m$ where $p$ is a prime number and if $p^r|m$ but $p^{r+1}\nmid m$, consider $$\binom{p^{\alpha}m}{p^{\alpha}}=\frac{p^{\alpha}m(p^{\alpha}m-1)\dots(p^{\alpha}m-i)\dots(p^{\alpha}m-p^{\alpha}+1)}{p^{\alpha}(p^{\alpha}-1)\dots(p^{\alpha}-i)\dots(p^{\alpha}-p^{\alpha}+1)}$$ 
>   What power of $p$ divides $\binom{p^{\alpha}m}{p^{\alpha}}$?

The book then says that the power of $p$ dividing $p^{\alpha}m-i$ is the same as that dividing $p^{\alpha}-i$. How to prove this?

Comment: Perhaps you meant $n=p^rm$ and $p^r\mid n$ and $p^{r+1}\nmid n$?  Same power and dividing $n$ and not $m$.

Comment: I am sorry, Michael, but I meant $n=p^{\alpha}m$ while $r$ is highest power of $p$ dividing $m$. I think here ${\alpha}$ is any positive natural number, irrespective of what $r$ is.

Comment: Usually, when one writes these statements, $m$ is meant to be relatively prime to $p$.  That this is not the case makes the entire statement suspect.  The statement in the question you asked is true when $m$ is relatively prime to $p$ and false when it is not.

Comment: But I do not think that my book intends that they are relative primes!

Comment: Let $n=8$, $p=2$, $\alpha=1$, and $i=4$.  Then $m=4$ and $4\mid n-i=4$, but $4\nmid p^\alpha-i=-2$.

Comment: But there $i=4$ is invalid: Since in $\binom{p^{\alpha}m}{p^{\alpha}}=\frac{p^{\alpha}m(p^{\alpha}m-1)\dots(p^{\alpha}m-i)\dots(p^{\alpha}m-p^{\alpha}+1)}{p^{\alpha}(p^{\alpha}-1)\dots(p^{\alpha}-i)\dots(p^{\alpha}-p^{\alpha}+1)}$, we have to have $i\le p^α−1$, so, in your example, only $i=0$ and $i=1$ are valid. This question occurred to me while reading Herstein's Topics in Algebra, 2nd edition, page 92. So I do not think that anything is wrong in the question. You can see almost exact wording on the mentioned page.

Comment: Be careful in Herstein's topics in algebra because it has many typos.  For example, the proof of Sylow's theorems uses the same notation for two different concepts in the same proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50584/discussion-between-silent-and-michael-burr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $p^\beta$ divides $p^\alpha m-i$.

- If $\beta\leq\alpha$, then we know that $p^\beta$ divides $i$ using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  Namely, $p^\alpha m-i=p^\beta k$ so $i=p^\beta(p^{\alpha-\beta}m-k)$.  Therefore $p^\beta$ divides $p^\alpha-i$.
- If $\beta>\alpha$, then $i\geq p^\beta>p^\alpha$, but this is not possible since $i<p^\alpha$ by its definition in the problem.  Therefore, this case is impossible.

Therefore, the power of $p$ dividing $p^\alpha-i$ is at least the power of $p$ dividing $p^\alpha m-i$.

Suppose now that $p^\gamma$ divides $p^\alpha-i$.

- If $\gamma\leq \alpha$, then $p^\gamma$ divides $i$, so $p^\gamma$ divides $p^\alpha m-i$.
- If $\gamma>\alpha$, then $p^\gamma$ is dividing a smaller, but positive number, which is not possible.

This completes the proof (in the special case of the question).